# neo4j 2.1.1 How to setup logging to analyze "Unknown Error"

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to load lot of data exported from my SQL Server as csv file in to neo4j using the following query:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:e:/temp/sql_backup/events.csv" AS csvLine
MERGE (dtStart:Date { Name: REPLACE (SUBSTRING(csvLine.VT_Start,0,10),"-","")})
MERGE (dtEnd:Date { Name: REPLACE (SUBSTRING(csvLine.VT_End,0,10),"-","")})
MERGE (ev:Event  { EventId : csvLine.EventID})
ON CREATE SET ev = {
    EventId : csvLine.EventID,
    TagId : csvLine.TagID,  
    EventTypeId : csvLine.EventTypeID, 
    IntervalIdentifier : csvLine.AlarmID,    
    VT_Start : csvLine.VT_Start ,  
    VT_End : csvLine.VT_End,  
    Suppressed : csvLine.Suppressed, 
    system_messagetypename : csvLine.system_messagetypename,                                
    system_inputname : csvLine.system_inputname,
    system_spare1 : csvLine.system_spare1,
    Priority : csvLine.Priority,
    Console : csvLine.Console,
    Operator : csvLine.Operator,
    Message : csvLine.Message,
    Parameter : csvLine.Parameter,
    FromValue : csvLine.FromValue,
    ToValue : csvLine.ToValue,
    UnitOfMeasure : csvLine.UnitOfMeasure,
    Limit : csvLine.Limit,
    Value : csvLine.Value,
    User1 : csvLine.User1,
    BlockName : csvLine.BlockName }

MERGE (al:Alarm{ Name:  csvLine.AlarmID})
MERGE (pr:Priority{ Name:  csvLine.Priority})
MERGE (con:Console{ Name:  csvLine.Console })
MERGE (op:Operator{ Name:  csvLine.Operator })
MERGE (prm:Parameter{ Name:  csvLine.Parameter })
MERGE (uom:UOM{ Name:  csvLine.UnitOfMeasure })
MERGE (user:User{ Name:  csvLine.User1 })
MERGE (blk:Block{ Name:  csvLine.BlockName })
MERGE (tag:Tag{ TagId:  csvLine.TagID })
MERGE (evt:EventType{ EventTypeID:  csvLine.EventTypeID })
CREATE UNIQUE  (con)<-[:FOR_CONSOLE]-(ev)-[:HAS_ALARM]->(al)
CREATE UNIQUE  (op)<-[:FOR_OPERATOR]-(ev)-[:HAS_PRIORITY]->(pr)
CREATE UNIQUE  (user)<-[:FOR_USER]-(ev)-[:HAS_UOM]->(uom)
CREATE UNIQUE  (blk)<-[:HAS_BLOCK]-(ev)-[:HAS_EVENT_TYPE]->(evt)
CREATE UNIQUE  (ev)-[:FOR_TAG]->(tag)
CREATE UNIQUE  (dtStart)<-[:DATE_VT_START]-(ev)-[:FOR_TAG]->(tag)-[:DATE_VT_END]->(dtEnd)
```

I see that this query runs for a while and i get an error like below:
[image]

I looked in to the data directory to check if there was any logs there that explains more details, but I can't find any logs generated there as well.

[neo4j documents](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-configuration.html) talks about editing `conf/neo4j-server.properties` but i don't see either a `config` folder or `logs` in my neo4j directory as shown below.[image]

only logs I see in that root folder is `nioneo_logical.log, tm_tx_log, active_tx_log`

Can someone please explain me how to setup debug logging in neo4j 2.1.1 so that I can see whats causing this error. I suspect it could be that my Laptop is running out of available RAM may be, so want to know if anyone think that neo4j crashes when it runs out available of RAM.

Also I noticed that the some data is created before the error is thrown, but no relationships queries are created, so is there anything wrong in the query itself? or its the error that is causing the issue of not creating the relationships.

**EDIT 1:**

BTW what happened to the neo4j 2.1.1 download? i don't find it in the neo4j site anymore !

**EDIT 2:**
I downloaded the latest version 2.1.2 and tried to run the query again and landed in the same issue. I think I kind of get the issue, the `periodic commit` is not useful as it looks to me that query first creates all the event nodes and then starts to run the create associations.

I reduced the size of events to 5000 and i got it to work, but when I increased it to 100000 it crashed again and there were 30000+ events in the database with no associations.

My conclusion is that: Either my query is incorrect, or the way Periodic commits are handled is not correct. This way we will run out of physical RAM when the dataset is large.

**Edit 3:**

Here is the output from the Shell, where the 1st query runs as it does not have any Create statements. 
[image]

Same runs from the Browser window though if the file size is not large.

Comment: That looks weird. I'd wait for Neo4j 2.1.2 which fixes some known issues in 2.1.1 an will be available shortly.

Comment: @StefanArmbruster: I downloaded 2.1.2 and tried again, but the issue still exists. I have updated my finding under Edit 2

Comment: Kiran, can you share the output from the shell where you run into the "PeriodicCommitInOpenTransactionException" ? Make sure to not use "begin" before that, as it creates an outer transaction. Also make sure to create constraints for the label-property pairs that you MERGE on.

Comment: @MichaelHunger: Please have a look at the Edit 3, that is the capture of my Shell commands

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you cannot find any errors in the logs is that long running queries in the Neo4j browser timeout at 60 seconds. This does not mean that the query actually failed, in fact it will run to completion.

For testing long running queries, please use the Neo4j Shell, which does not have a timeout.

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/shell.html

Comment: I think it ran in to either one of the 2 issues; in the shell as you suggested first i got an error suggesting `PeriodicCommitInOpenTransactionException: Executing queries that use periodic commit in an open transaction is not possible.` and when i removed the `Periodic Commit` from the query i ran in to the following `Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is:  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. I am sure that we will need `Periodic Commit` due to size of data, but I am not sure how to fix that. Do you happen to have a suggestion?

Comment: Increase your heap size, set periodic commit to 500-1000 operations per commit. USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000

Comment: I am unable to use the `PERIODIC COMMIT 1000 ` from within the shell as i then run in to the first exception `PeriodicCommitInOpenTransactionException: Executing queries that use periodic commit in an open transaction is not possible` is there something different i have to do to run that command from withing the shell compared to browser. Also I was using the command like this : `$ cypher 2.1.1 USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000...` i think it fails while creating the relationsships, not sure but the stack trace looked like that.

Comment: There may be some datastore issues with 2.1.1. We're working on resolving these issues and will release 2.1.2 very soon. I think it is a good idea to wait for that before proceeding.

Comment: Thanks, now I also understand how the link to download that version is no longer available. however a message on the website suggesting why its taken back would have really helped I think.

Comment: You're absolutely right Kiran. Thanks for being patient, we're working the best we can to rectify the issues. I'll follow up internally to see about better communications.

Comment: I have downloaded the latest version, and looks like the issue still exists. I have updated my comment under Edit 2