# can't debug "Unknown error" in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I need to load ~29 million nodes from a CSV file (with USING PERIODIC COMMIT) but I'm getting "Unknown error" after the first ~75k nodes are loaded. I've tried changing the commit size (250, 500, and 1000), increasing the java heap (-Xmx4096m), and using [memory mapping](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-io-examples.html), but nothing changes (except the number of nodes that get loaded - with commit size 500 I get "Unkown error" after 75,499 nodes and with commit size 250 I get "Unkown error" after 75,749 nodes).

I'm doing it in the browser, using Neoj4 2.1.7 on a remote machine with 10GB of RAM and Windows Server 2012. Here's my code:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV FROM "file:/C:/Users/thiago.marzagao/Desktop/CSVs/cnpj.csv" AS node
CREATE (:PessoaJuridica {id: node[0], razaoSocial: node[1], nomeFantasia: node[2], CNAE: node[3], porte: node[4], dataAbertura: node[5], situacao: node[6], dataSituacao: node[7], endereco: node[8], CEP: node[9], municipio: node[10], UF: node[11], tel: node[12], email: node[13]})
```

The really bad part is that the `nioneo_logical.log` files have some weird encoding that no text editor can't figure out. All I see is `eÿÿÿÿ414141`, `ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ`, etc. The `messages` file, in turn, ends with hundreds of garbage collection warnings, like these:

```
2015-02-05 17:16:54.596+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for 304ms.
2015-02-05 17:16:55.033+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for 238ms.
2015-02-05 17:16:55.471+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for 231ms.
```

I've found somewhat related [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134969/neo4j-2-1-1-how-to-setup-logging-to-analyze-unknown-error) but not exactly what I'm looking for.

What am I missing?

Comment: can you please add your schema and the query you use to load the csv

Comment: There's no schema: the database starts empty and the nodes I'm trying to load are all there is for now. The code I use to load the CSV, in turn, is in the question above (the code block that starts with "USING PERIODIC COMMIT...").

Comment: Have you tried it in the shell?

Comment: Nope. Can it make a difference? I'll give it a try then.

Comment: those log files are logical logs (write ahead logs for transactions) the log files your looking for are data/log/*.log and data/graph.db/messages.log

Comment: Thiago would you be able to share your dataset? If so, please send it to michael at neo4j.com

Comment: Sorry Michael, can't do that - it's private data like phone numbers and (the Brazilian equivalent of) SSNs (I work in government). Also, sorry I only saw your msg now - I was in meetings all day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser is the worst choice to run such an import, also because of http timeouts.

Enough RAM helps as well as a fast disk.

Try to use `bin/Neo4jShell.bat` which connects to the running server. And best make sure the CSV file is locally available.

those nioneo.*log files are logical logs (write ahead logs for transactions)

**the log files your looking for are data/log/*.log and data/graph.db/messages.log**

Something else that you can **please** do, is to open the Browser-Inspector, go to the Network/Requests tab and re-run the query, so that you can get the raw HTTP-response, we just discussed that and will try to dump it directly to the JS console in the future.

Comment: Ok, I'll try the shell and report back.

Comment: I switched to the shell interface and to my MacBook (it has more RAM - 16GB -, disk is SSD, and Neo4j seems better documented when it comes to Linux/OSX). Still no joy. I don't get any error messages, but after a while Neo4j seems stuck - nothing has been written to disk since yesterday at 5am (by which time the database folder had achieved 4.85GB). After that time all there is in the `messages.log` file is a bunch of `[org.neo4j]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for {200-700}ms.` messages.

Comment: This time I let the application set the heap dynamically and I didn't tweak the memory mapping settings, but I'm still using periodic commits, so I think I shouldn't be running into any problems. I'll keep googling and tweaking for a couple more days, hopefully at some point I'll figure it out.

Comment: Ok, next week I should have a server with 128GB of RAM - that should get the job done.

Comment: Fixed! I kept tweaking the memory mapping and the heap size and I finally got it to work - using the shell and "import-cypher". @Michael Hunger, thank you so much for the help and for creating neo4j-shell-tools!

Comment: No 128GB of RAM needed, it worked on my 16GB MacBook.

Comment: I really don't understand why the original load csv statement didn't work on your mac, it looks totally ok to me at least. I'd love to see it just pull through the CSV data, like I explain here: http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv

Comment: Nothing is displayed, memory and CPU usage keeps increasing, then I run out of memory. If I limit the number of lines then the lines are displayed - and they look correct (these are personal data of lots of people, so I can't share them). If I use USING PERIODIC COMMIT I get an error message saying I can't use that with a non-updating command. So, I don't understand why import-cypher worked but LOAD CSV didn't. Maybe something related to USING PERIODIC COMMIT?